# how to align jsplumb flowchart nodes when they are drag and dropped by user

Tags: jsplumb

I use jsPlumb to display flowcharts in my angular app, and I would like to have the flowchart nodes aligned, even when the user drag and drops them.

To do this, I think I need to bind a function on the drop event of nodes, and in this function, I will reposition the node.

But I can't figure how to do it, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I found in the doc it is natively supported by JSPLUMB using grid:

```
dragOptions: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                zIndex: 2000,
                grid: [20, 20],
                containment: 'notNegative'
            }
```